# Why concatenate simple strings instead writing it directly?

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

Today I found a code snipped which has multiple strings concatenate together with `+`. But why separate a string like `'<script ...`? Has it something to do with bots or do some developers try do make it harder to find some specific code?

```
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" s'+'rc="' + RecaptchaState.server + 'js/recaptcha.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

I really do not see any benefit of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the html parser sees `</script>`, even inside javascript, it will treat it as the closing tag for the containing script. Breaking it up makes the HTML parser happy